# AS2 bitmap resizing external image anti-aliasing (Actionscript 2)

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm using the dreded AS2 (not by choice) and working with images externally loaded.

I know that

targetClip.forceSmoothing = true;

...exists, but it still doesn't seem to be doing much at all.

The images externally loaded are really big in dimensions and when made smaller in the flash, they pixelate.

Perhaps forceSmoothing is the best method but...
I'm thinking there may be a way to resave the external bitmap resized and use that, instead of resizing a bitmap as a vector.

Any ideas?

Also, I've got an AS3 version of this, so if you know how I can do it in that too, then great. But it seems they do not want to use that yet.

Answer (score 0):

in as2:
add this class to your project [BitmapLoader](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/BitmapLoader.as)

and use like that:

```
var loader : BitmapLoader = new BitmapLoader(true);
loader.addListener(this);
loader.loadBitmap("http://foo.tr/example.jpg", this, "doneLoading" );
```

in as3 :

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
loader.load(new URLRequest("1.jpg"))
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);

function doneLoad(e:Event){
   var bitmap:Bitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap
   bitmap.smoothing = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ersil, I used the doneLoad part of that code and it works for the as3.

Comment: I've found - imageHolder._quality = "BEST" - which I can use for the AS2, it works but then upon publish and on the web, it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the image data? If you're doing it with the BitmapData class, you can use a matrix together with the scale() command to shrink it.

http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/flash/geom/Matrix.html
http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/flash/display/BitmapData.html